# Output ADODB.RecordSet as JSON

Tags: json, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm trying to change my application so that it **outputs JSON instead of HTML** when it makes an AJAX request for some data. I have an ADODB RecordSet. I need to loop through it row-by-row and add/change/remove different values. Then I need to take all the modified rows and `response.write` them as JSON. I'm using JSON2.asp so my application already supports `JSON.parse` & `JSON.stringify` but I can't get it to spit out the multi-dimensional array as JSON.

```
set rs = conn.execute(strQuery)
if Not rs.EOF Then
    rsArray = rs.GetRows() 'This pulls in all the results of the RecordSet as a 2-dimensional array
    columnCount = ubound(rsArray,1)
    rowCount = ubound(rsArray,2)
    For rowIndex = 0 to rowCount 'Loop through rows as the outer loop
        rsArray(3,0) = "somethingelse"
    Next 'Move on to next row if there is one

    response.write JSON.stringify(rsArray) & " _______ "
End If
```

I just need to be able to go through the results of my database query, modify the results, and then output the modified results in JSON format. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `JSON2.asp` implementation doesn't have a "Load From Database" function which means you will have to implement something to convert the `ADODB.Recordset` to a JSON structure yourself.

If you are willing to use a different script there is an implementation by [RCDMK](https://github.com/rcdmk) on GitHub that does have a `LoadRecordset()` method, it's called [JSON object class 3.5.3](https://github.com/rcdmk/aspJSON).

This makes loading data from an `ADODB.Recordset` really straightforward.

```vb
<!-- #include virtual="/jsonObject.class.asp" -->
<%
Response.LCID = 2057
'...
Dim rs: Set rs = conn.execute(strQuery)

Dim JSON: Set JSON = New JSONobject
Call JSON.LoadRecordset(rs)
Call Response.Clear()
Response.ContentType = "application/json"
Call JSON.Write()
%>
```

*<sup>Code has been tested using a disconnected recordset, the `...` here denote assumed code to setup your recordset, connection etc</sup>*

It's worth noting you could write this yourself, it's not a huge leap to loop through an `ADODB.Recordset` and build a JSON string. However, I would argue against for a few reasons;

1. It is a time-consuming exercise.
2. Very easy to miss something *(like checking for numeric data types, when generating output)*.
3. Depending on how it is coded can make it awkward to maintain *(For example, if not injecting property names directly from the recordset and choosing to "hardcode" them instead)*.
4. Why *[reinvent the wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel)* ? There are a lot of public implementations in the wild that deal with the issues raised here. Admittedly, some are better than others, but it takes five minutes to include them and give it a try.

---

Just for completeness here is my local test code using a disconnected recordset

```
<!-- #include virtual="/jsonObject.class.asp" -->
<%
Call init()

Sub init()
  Dim fields: fields = Array(Array("title", adVarChar, 50), Array("firstname", adVarChar, 50), Array("lastname", adVarChar, 50), Array("age", adInteger, 4))
  Dim rs: Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  Call InsertRow(rs, fields, Array("Mr", "Joe", "Bloggs", 31))
  Call InsertRow(rs, fields, Array("Mr", "John", "Smith", 42))

  Response.LCID = 2057

  Dim JSON: Set JSON = New JSONobject
  Call JSON.LoadRecordset(rs)
  Call Response.Clear()
  Response.ContentType = "application/json"
  Call JSON.Write()
End Sub

Sub InsertRow(ByVal rs, fields, values)
  With rs
    If rs.State <> adStateOpen Then
      For Each fld In fields
        Call .Fields.Append(fld(0), fld(1), fld(2))
      Next

      .CursorLocation = adUseClient
      .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
      Call .Open()
    End If
    Call .AddNew()
    For i = 0 To UBound(fields, 1)
      .Fields(fields(i)(0)).Value = values(i)
    Next
    Call .Update()
    Call .MoveFirst()
  End With
End Sub
%>
```

Output:

```
{"data":[{"title":"Mr","firstname":"Joe","lastname":"Bloggs","age":31},{"title":"Mr","firstname":"John","lastname":"Smith","age":42}]}
```

Comment: Could you please show an example of actually editing the recordset before calling `JSON.Write()`? I can't seem to figure out how to loop through the JSON and remove/add fields to each "row". The documentation doesn't show an example of this while actually looping through the result of the `LoadRecordset`.

Comment: Sorry @tylerl, had assumed you already knew how to work with `ADODB.Recordset` to add, update, etc. The example I have given in my test example was using a "disconnected recordset", not hugely different but allows me to load sample data as a test. I assumed you would be returning data already stored in a database ready to output to JSON.

Comment: So is this not going to work unless the Recordset is already exactly the way I want it when it comes from the DB?

Comment: @tylerl wouldn't that make sense? If you want to restructure the returned recordset then you could use the approach I have above, by building a disconnected recordset containing the data structured how you want it. But honestly just making sure the data is already structured correctly to pass into `LoadRecordset()` is by far the best option.

Comment: ADODB.Recordset error '800a0e78'

Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.

/test.asp, line 31

Comment: @pee2pee you're not returning any data to the `ADODB.Recordset` so it is coming back with a `State` of  `adStateClosed`, check your query is returning data and try again. Also, comments are not for extended discussion. If you want help with this show us your code by [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) explaining what is happening and any errors you are receiving.

Comment: @pee2pee Not sure which one you tried but the first example says *"Code has been tested using a disconnected recordset, the ... here denote assumed code to setup your recordset, connection etc"*, so there is some setup on your part you can't just copy and run it. The second example is fully tested and works and have just re-run to test it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go.  This works for me.

```
set rs = conn.execute(strQuery)
c=0
Response.write "["
Do Until rs.eof 

    'Assign variables here with whatever you need to change 
    title = rs(0)
    fName = rs(1)
    lName = rs(2)
    empID = rs(3)

    With Response
        if c > 0 then .write ", "
        .write "{" & chr(34) & "Title" & chr(34) & " : " & chr(34) & title & chr(34) & ", " & chr(34) & "FirstName" & chr(34) & " : " & chr(34) & fName & chr(34) & ", "
        .write       chr(34) & "LastName" & chr(34) & " : " & chr(34) & lName & chr(34) & ", " & chr(34) & "EmpID" & chr(34) & " : " & chr(34) & empID & chr(34) & "}"
    End With

    c = c + 1
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
Response.write "]"
```

This will write your JSON object directly to the page.

Comment: You could use `rs.Fields(n).Name` to fill the property names in without having to hardcode them. You also don't distinguish between numeric and string values. That is basically what `LoadRecordset()` does in the [JSON object class 3.5.3](https://github.com/rcdmk/aspJSON) class, which is why I prefer not to reinvent the wheel in these situations.

Comment: @Lankymart Well, since OP wants to manipulate the data before putting it into a JSON object, I showed him this which is the way I personally handle this situation since it gives me complete control over everything as I build the object.  Honestly though, I have never used LoadRecordSet() and am now curious about trying it out.  Thanks.

Comment: That makes sense, the OP was already using `JSON2.asp` so thought suggesting another class that does the job wouldn't be a too much of a stretch. It is pretty good, and you still have a degree of control over how the data is structured.

Answer (score -3):

try setting content-type to "application/json" on top of your asp page.

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<%
Option Explicit
Response.Buffer=True
Response.ContentType="application/json"
Response.Charset="utf-8"
'' rest of your code.. your db operations
'' response write your json
%>
```

Comment: That would allow the browser to detect the response as JSON. First though, you need to convert the multidimensional array into JSON, which is the guts of the question.